# Cannot dump Stack Overflow XML file into SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Cannot dump Stack Overflow XML file into SQL Server 2008.
Could you please explain how I can do it step-by-step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if [this](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-tutorial/data-mining-the-stackoverflow-database/) helps. If not try to post what you have done so far and what errors you get.